# php variable converting to JSON object

Tags: php, json

I want to make an array of json objects having the structure as follows:

```
{
    "client-mac": "0C:D2:B5:68:73:24",
    "client-dbm": "-82",
    "clientManuf": "unknown"
}
```

I am using following php code to get this result:

```
$clientMac = $clients->{'client-mac'};
$clientStrength = $clients->{'snr-info'}->{'last_signal_dbm'};
$clientManuf = $clients->{'client-manuf'};
$jsonObject = array('client-mac' => $clientMac,
                    'client-dbm' => $clientStrength,
                    'clientManuf' => $clientManuf);
$jsonString = json_encode($jsonObject);
```

The problem is I am getting following json string:

```
{"client-mac":{
                 "0":"0C:D2:B5:68:73:24"
              },
 "client-dbm":{
                 "0":"-82"
              },
 "clientManuf":{"0":"Unknown"}
}
```

Why I am getting those extra keys as "0"? And how can I get my desired output? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your source data has one more nested level with one key/value pair.

You could use `reset` on them to just pick the first value from that:

```
array('client-mac' => reset($clientMac),
      'client-dbm' => reset($clientStrength),
      'clientManuf' => reset($clientManuf));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$clientMac`, `$clientStrength` and `$clientManuf` are objects, not literal strings. You have to change the first three lines in the following way,

```
$clientMac = $clients->{'client-mac'}->{'0'};
$clientStrength = $clients->{'snr-info'}->{'last_signal_dbm'}->{'0'};
$clientManuf = $clients->{'client-manuf'}->{'0'};
...
```